# Can’t Display A Microsoft Word.doc document on UIView Controller

Tags: iphone, ios

I’m using the code below to display pdfs or filename.doc Microsoft Word documents.  It works fine when I use a ofType:@:”pdf”, but my code crashes when I use ofType:@:”doc” or ofType:@:”docx”.  The Word document is mostly text and a few url links.  Any help appreciated.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"C9" ofType:@"doc"];
pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];}
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl]];
```

Comment: Do you have some more information about the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, it looks like you're already using a `UIWebView`.

Here is some code I've used in the past.

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

In viewDidLoad (change webView frame to whatever you need)..

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

[self loadDocument:@"file.doc" inView:webView];
```

Comment: Thank you both.  Below is the output from the run.  The only difference is that I changed file.pdf to file.doc.

Comment: Did you try this code?  I've created `file.doc` and imported into a test project and confirmed it does indeed work.  When you imported your document, did you make sure to add it to your target by checking the box next to your projects name?

Comment: I checked to make sure the file had been added to the target (never had done that before)....and it hadn't.  Not sure I understand this.  All my pdfs were listed and I loaded them the same way as the doc file, but I had to manually add the doc file.  Any clue why?  Regardless, thanks.  Once I added it, my code worked fine.  Thanks again.  I'll accept this.

Comment: Not sure why you had to re-add it.  A common mistake I've seen is that people don't select add to their target project.  Sometimes the checkbox seems to be selected by default, sometimes not.  In any case, glad it is working for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [QLPreviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display these document types.

For the crash, are you sure the file exists at the specified location? Check it's actually being copied to the bundle and that there is a file at that path / URL before you use it.

Comment: Thank you both.  Below is the output from the run.  The only difference is that I changed file.pdf to file.doc.  I double checked the file location, and it was fine. I'll tried this alernative language also in the meanwhile. 2013-05-19 16:41:27.101 Camino[646:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
TOOK OUT ALL THE NUMBER HER
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: Turned out it wasn't being added.  Thanks for you help.